# Why does mypy flag "Item None has no attribute x" error even if I check for None?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Trying to do Python (3.8.8) with type hinting and getting errors from mypy (0.931) that I can't really understand.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('plant_catalog.xml')  # read in file and parse as XML
root = tree.getroot()  # get root node
for plant in root:  # loop through children
    if plant.find("LIGHT") and plant.find("LIGHT").text == "sun" 
        print("foo")
```

This raises the mypy error `Item "None" of "Optional[Element]" has no attribute "text"`.
But why? I do check for the possibility of `plant.find("LIGHT")` returning `None` in the first half of the if clause. The second part accessing the `.text` attribute isn't even executed if the first part fails.

If I modify to

```py
    lights = plant.find("LIGHT")
    if lights:
        if lights.text == selection:            
            print("foo")
```

the error is gone.

So is this because the `plant` object might still change in between the first check and the second? But assigning to a variable doesn't automatically copy the content, its still just a reference to an object that might change. So why does it pass the second time?

(Yes, I know that repeating the `.find()` twice is also not time-efficient.)

Comment: `mypy` doesn't know that `plant.find()` is idempotent.

Comment: Assigning to a variable assigns a reference to the value. The variable can't change from an object to None without being reassigned.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. The details of an object referenced by a variable can change, but not the reference from an object to None. Mind to change this into a proper answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mypy` doesn't know that `plant.find("LIGHT")` always returns the same value, so it doesn't know that your test is a proper guard.

So you need to assign it to a variable. As far as mypy is concerned, the variable can't change from one object to another without being reassigned, and its contents can't change if you don't perform some other operation on it.

Comment: Well, the contents can change if something else performs operations on it. In case of an XML node from ElementTree you are probably right, but for generic objects that statement is too wide. Other threads might change the object. Or it might represent memory content updated by interrupts/DMA.

Comment: True, but I guess mypy makes the same simplifying assumptions I did.