# mypy error [union-attr] Item "None" of "Optional[SparkSession]" has no attribute "createDataFrame"

Tags: pyspark, mypy

I am running unittest and pyspark.
Library versions:

- pyspark==3.2.2
- mypy == 0.961
- python == 3.8.1

```py
class TestParsingFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    This class performs for functions on mintel_import.py file
    """

    db_name = None
    spark = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.test_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory().name
        findspark.init()
        cls.spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").getOrCreate()

    def test_df_remove_active_ingredient_pattern(self):
        input_df = self.spark.createDataFrame(
            data=[
                (
                    "9253090",
                    "This input text is TRANSFORMED",
                ),
                
            ],
            schema="ID: string, INPUT_TEXT: string",
        )

        expected_result = self.spark.createDataFrame(
            data=[
                ("9253090", "thisinputtextistransformed"),
                
            ],
            schema="ID: string, INPUT_TEXT: string",
        )
        result_df = transfor_text(
            input_df, col_name="INPUT_TEXT"
        )
        rows = result_df.sort("ID").collect()
        expected_rows = expected_result.sort("ID").collect()
        # Compare dataframes row by row
        for row_num, row in enumerate(rows):
            assert row == expected_rows[row_num], f"Error on row: {row_num}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

After running `mypy` I get this error:

```py
error: Item "None" of "Optional[SparkSession]" has no attribute "createDataFrame"  [union-attr]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mypy` infers the `spark` field as `Optional` (and it is - it starts as `None`).

From its perspective if you make use of `spark` without checking if it's `None` first, it's an error, because it has no way to know that `setUpClass` will *always* be called first. Hence a message that `None` doesn't support `createDataFrame`.

Add an `if` or `assert` to check that it's not `None` and `mypy` should be happy.

Answer (score 1):

See this relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70938215/why-does-mypy-flag-item-none-has-no-attribute-x-error-even-if-i-check-for-none) , assigning `self.spark` to a variable first should also make `mypy` happy.